# Why I lost my variable after browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I have "react actions" file. And something going wrong.

```
'use strict';

var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var constants = require('../constants/constants');
var URIjs = require('URIjs');

function loadPageData(url) {
    //ajax call
}

var InputsRowActions = {

  //some methods, like this
  changePage: function(page) {
    //work with url params..
    loadPageData(url);
  }

  console.log(URIjs) //-> undefined

};

module.exports = InputsRowActions;
```

I can't understand, why URIjs didn't defined ?
My Gulp browserify task:

```
var b = browserify('./app/assets/react/app.react.js', {
    debug: true
  });

b = watchify(b);
b.transform('reactify');
b.on('update', bundle);

function bundle(fileName) {

  return b
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.react.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/javascripts/'));
}

gulp.task('browserify', bundle);
```

I have same problem, with requiring 'lodash'.

Comment: Because you don't use it, and you don't export it. It is as useless as appendix.

Comment: @Amadan hm, it's example only! Ofc, I try to use it. Update example with console.log
How I can access to URIjs in this console.log line ?